# Is it Possible to use the Dependency Injection (DI) in 3.x base Eclipse code imported on Luna (Eclipse e4)

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, e4

Currently I'm trying to migrate my Eclipse 3.x code to e4 and I would like to access the e4 Dependency Injection (DI) feature. I'm not doing a complete migration as described [here](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2013/february/article3.php). Just I'm importing the 3.x sources on top of e4 to gain access the DI feature for Business logics (and not for UI).

I observed that the DI is not working if I follow the this approach. Any ways to acheive DI in Eclipse 3.x sources imported on Luna ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an object is just created using `new xxxx` then it is not injected.

Objects created by Eclipse from a description in the Application.e4xmi (and fragments) are injected automatically (so handlers, parts, ....). @Creatable objects created by the injector are also injected.

You can inject other objects using `ContextInjectionFactory`, this requires that you have access to the `IEclipseContext`.

```java
MyClass myClass = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyClass.class, eclipseContext);
```

creates a new instance of a class with injection.

```java
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

ContextInjectionFactory.inject(myClass, eclipseContex);
```

Injects an object after it has been created using `new`. In this case the class Constructor cannot use injection.

Note: There are multiple Eclipse Contexts in a tree structure. A part has its own context, so if you create the object using that context the object will only be available in the part (and any handlers etc. associated with the part).

To make an object available everywhere use the Eclipse Context from the `MApplication` (call the `getContext()` method).

Comment: Greg: Thanks for your answer. I tried  "ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyClass.class, eclipseContext)" and  the MyClass constructor was getting injected into the context. After adding it to the eclipse context, If I try to access the value from other classes using "@Inject MyClass myclass"  annotation I'm always getting its value as "null". Please correct me if I went wrong anywhere.

Comment: Added some details of the Eclipse Context hierarchy to the answer.

Comment: Thank You Greg, It works for me :) and a special thanks for explaining the context hierarchy... It helped me a lot in gaining understanding of the Eclipse context.